# Pulling ipywidget value manually

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have this code ipython code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import time

w = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['Addition', 'Multiplication', 'Subtraction'],
    value='Addition',
    description='Task:',
)

def on_change(change):
    print("changed to %s" % change['new'])

w.observe(on_change)

display(w)
```

It works as expected. When the value of the widget changes, the `on_change` function gets triggered. However, I want to run a long computation and periodically check for updates to the widget. For example:

```
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    # pull for changes to w here.
    # if w.has_changed:
    #     print(w.value)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, I seem to be able to do the desired polling with

```
import IPython
ipython = IPython.get_ipython()
ipython.kernel.do_one_iteration()
```

(I'd still love to have some feedback on whether this works by accident or design.)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, although for me it was a button on_click

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in the most recent version of `ipykernel`? This no longer works, I get `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Kernel.do_one_iteration' was never awaited`. I've tried doing it using await, but then I get the error message `Queue Empty`...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use threads and hook into the ZMQ event loop. This gist illustrates an example:

https://gist.github.com/maartenbreddels/3378e8257bf0ee18cfcbdacce6e6a77e

Also see https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/642.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the OP's self answer, this does work. It forces the widgets to sync with the kernel at an arbitrary point in the loop. This can be done right before the accessing the `widget.value`.

So the full solution would be:

```py
import IPython
ipython = IPython.get_ipython()

last_val = 0
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    ipython.kernel.do_one_iteration()
    new_val = w.value
    if new_val != old_val:
        print(new_val)
        old_val = new_val
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement to the `ipython.kernel.do_one_iteration` call used

```py
# Max iteration limit, in case I don't know what I'm doing here...
for _ in range(100):
  ipython.kernel.do_one_iteration()
  if ipython.kernel.msg_queue.empty():
    break
```

In my case, I had a number of UI elements, that could be clicked multiple times between `do_one_iteration` calls, which will process them one at a time, and with a 1 second time delay, that could get annoying. This will process at most 100 at a time. Tested it by mashing a button multiple times, and now they all get processes as soon as the `sleep(1)` ends.